# RISC-V calling convention

Tags: riscv

I have read this alr : https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/riscv-calling.pdf

but still can't figure out which register RISC-V put the argument in.

The code fibonacci.c is like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int fibonacci(int);

int main () {
    unsigned long long int ret;

    for (int i = 0; i < 94; i++) {
        ret = fibonacci(i);
        printf("%llu\n", ret);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the .s code format is like this :

```
.global fibonacci
.type fibonacci, %function

.align 2
# unsigned long long int fibonacci(int n);
fibonacci:  
    # insert code here
    # Green card here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1617/ECAD+Arch/files/docs/RISCVGreenCardv8-20151013.pdf
    
    ret
```

I have tried changing the value in a0, a1 register, but the output still didnt change.

like this :

```
.global fibonacci
.type fibonacci, %function

.align 2
# unsigned long long int fibonacci(int n);
fibonacci:  
    # insert code here
    add a0, a0, a0
    addi a1, zero, 1
    # Green card here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1617/ECAD+Arch/files/docs/RISCVGreenCardv8-20151013.pdf
    
    ret
```

The output is still
0
1
2
3
...
...
...
90
91
92
93

Comment: Your change to the assembly should have an effect. My best guess as to why you are not seeing a change is you are linking an old version of the assembly. Please include the steps to compile and link you are using.

Comment: LOL I found the bug, i pull the code from docker, but i'm coding on my IDE, it doesnt change the code in the docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calling abi for your fibonacci function is just a0 for both the input and output (for 32 bit a1 is also used for output).

[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cf4Gq1) is an incredibly useful tool to investigate C -> Assembly. Following a call to `fibonacci`, the C code moves `a0` into `-32(sp)` and then into `a1` for the following `printf`.

Comment: The unprivileged RISC-V spec covers the Calling Convention in Chapter 25. a0 - a7 can be used for function arguments. You can also see the link to understand the calling convention https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyjtOdgt2n8&t=734s .

Comment: Notably the RISC-V (RV) specification does not specify which arguments are placed into which registers. Specifically with regards to C you must refer to the C calling convention on RV for the details; arguments larger than one register, more than 8 arguments and varargs are all cases where there isn't a single obvious way to follow the RV specification. Unfortunately, the C calling convention on RV does not have a nice document that I am aware of.